# Add children to wrap panel

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm adding rectangles to a wrap panel like this:

```
For i = 0 to 20
wrapPanel.children.add()
next
```

I would like to use this loop because I don't want to specify the limit:

```
Do
wrapPanel.children.add()
Loop
```

But how can I break the loop when the wrap panel is filled? For example the loop would stop when the wrap panel can't display a rectangle in its full height or width.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a function to tell you the WrapPanel is filled. You'll probably need to do your own calculations to find that out.

Comment: @ArjanEinbu How to calculate it? Or would it be simpler to use Canvas instead?

Comment: I don't think canvas has a property or function to tell you when it is full either.

Comment: What if the panel is resized after you add items to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working! I'm using Canvas instead of Wrap Panel. Here's the working code:

```
for y = 0 to Canvas.height - Rectangle.height Step Rectangle.height
 for x = 0 to Canvas.width - Rectangle.width Step Rectangle.width
  Canvas.sety(Rectangle,y)
  Canvas.setx(Rectangle,x)

  Canvas.children.add(Rectangle)
 next
next
```

Answer (score 2):

this is giving error "Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget."
I want to read data from xml file using user control.

```
    List<careeroption> qz = new List<careeroption>();
        qz = KompkinDP.GetQuizList(CareerID.ToString());
        foreach (careeroption q in qz)
        {
            UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();

            for (int i = 0; i < q.CareerOptionQuiz.Count; i++)
            {
                uc.QuizName = q.CareerOptionQuiz[i];

                wrap1.Children.Add(uc);
            }
           // wrap1.Children.Add(uc);
        }
```